# Incorrect Encoder tick counts using Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, sensor, arduino, dc-motor

[image]Hi I have a DC motor with encoder which has a PPR count of 990 (No load RPM = 107). However, I tried to read the number of ticks (on a Raspberry Pi 3B) by rotating the wheel  1 turn and I get a PPR count way too low, let's say 200 (It varies each time). The following is my Python code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

enc_L = 4; tick_L = 0;  # Left motor encoder pin

sleep(1)

def my_callback_L(channel):
    global tick_L
    tick_L+=1
    print(tick_L)

GPIO.setup(enc_L, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.add_event_detect(enc_L, GPIO.RISING,callback=my_callback_L)
```

Now I tried to do the same thing on an Arduino Nano and to my surprise, the Nano gave exactly 990 PPR. The following is my Arduino code.

```
const int enc_pin1 = 2;

volatile long ticks1 = 0;

int tpr = 990;     

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(enc_pin1, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(enc_pin1),countTicks1, RISING); 

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void countTicks1(){
  ticks1++;
  Serial.println(ticks1);

}
```

So my question is why is the Pi missing encoder counts? Is it due to bouncetime? Or is there some other issue?, and how do I get the correct tick values? I need it so that I can calculate motor RPM.

Answer (score 1):

Bouncetime may be part of the problem.  Do you expect pulses to be received at a rate of more than one per bouncetime?  I don't know what the default is.

An encoder normally has two outputs.  You appear to only use one.

If you actually have an encoder try

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py

If you are only interested in RPM try

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_read_RPM_py

---

There are at least two other factors to consider.

1. The Arduino program is (compiled) C++, the Pi program is (interpreted) Python.  A compiled program is likely to be more responsive and faster than an interpreted program.
2. Linux is a multi-user, multi-process, multi-tasking operating system with many activities acting in parallel.  The Arduino is neither multi-user, multi-process, nor multi-tasking.  The one Arduino script has total control of the CPU.

Comment: Hi Joan, Yes the encoder has 2 outputs, but I am not interested in direction, but only in getting RPM which should be possible by using just 1 pin.

Comment: Also, I saw these in the morning so will give them a try. But I was thinking that I wrote a small and simple code on Arduino and it gave me correct RPM and tick counts. What might be going wrong with an RPi.

Comment: @Nischal Added info to answer.

Comment: Thanks Joan. Will try the class you referred earlier in the eveing. But then should I read sensor data from arduino and just just use the Pi for computing ? Does it make the Pi less powerful when dealing with Sensors ?

Comment: The Pi should be fine.  For some tasks you might have to use C rather than Python.  I expect that pigpio code will capture all the edges.

Comment: Ok, but I was reading (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/fastest-hardware-interrupt-software) post where you had replied and it seems that guy again ran into troubles when he tried to do things with Python.

Comment: just so you're aware, there is a rotary encoder kernel module included with raspbian that does the hard work of keeping track of the count in low level code that could be read back in python. i'll see if i can put together an example later

Comment: @ James Kent that will be really helpful, although I can make an Arduino commincate with the Pi, but then it just unnecessarily complicates stuff and its not a one stop solution.

Comment: @Nischal The code worked fine until he made some unspecified changes or added some unspecified code.  I drew my own conclusions.  I'd be interested in testing the kernel solution but I expect pigpio will perform better (pigpio certainly works much, much better at reading the DHT22 compared to the kernel).

Comment: @joan I've used the kernel module in something else i did (using rotary encoder as volume control) and found it to be very fast and low load, i never found it dropping steps but with no noticeable cpu use (I think it's interrupt based?) the other added nicety is that rather than relying on callbacks into your code you can simply check the current count at any time

Comment: @JamesKent a rotary encoder for volume probably only has 12 to 16 detents as opposed to the 990 on the OP's.  You might do a revolution per second for perhaps a count of 24-32 pulses.  The OP's will be doing perhaps 3500 pulses in the same time (if configured as an encoder).

Comment: @joan sorry to clarify i was testing with a 400 ppr encoder and spinning much faster that you would a volume control in my initial tests, but I don't have an rpm figure

Comment: @JamesKent Fair enough.   I'd still bet that pigpio will do a better job then the kernel (i.e. I'd expect pigpio to use less time and handle higher pulses per second reliably).  Here is some code I use to generate test pulses http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_tx_RED

Answer (score 1):

I will only cover one issue (that is not covered is existing answer).

You are only looking at one of the outputs of the encoder. This output can bounce, therefore you have a bounce filter. This filter can cause you to miss edges, and get a low count.

If you take into consideration both outputs, then you can let it bounce (you need no filter). You may get a **little** back and forth jitter, but that is all. You will want to put on a bounce filter to remove very high frequencies, so as to reduce load on the software (not too many events to process). However when you use only one output, then no value for the bounce filter can ever be good enough ( e.g. a stopped motor, can easily produce an oscillating output that looks like a high RPM).

Design filter value, so that it works if motor is going at some good margin faster than maximum.

Comment: Actually bouncetime is not mentioned in the script in the question.  I believe the default to be no bouncetime but can't find any documentation (and can not be bothered to find and read the source code).

Comment: Are we talking about a hardware filter?

Comment: Where I said “You will want to put on a bounce filter to remove very high frequencies, so as to reduce load on the software”, then yes a hardware filter. You will need just a capacitor, and maybe a resister. (someone here should be able to direct to how to work this out.)

Answer (score 1):

Bouncing means you have **extra** edges in the signal, so the error you get from it can only be a **higher** count, not lower.

De-bouncing means your software ignores the edges which come faster than expected, so it can remove those extra edges, or, if the de-bounce time is too high, ignore legitimate edges, leading to a **lower** count. As far as I can tell there is **no de-bounce** present in your code.

Since Arduino counts the edges correctly, I'd say that bouncing is not a problem here. Your Python code is simply too slow to count the pulses, so it misses most of them.

Using both A and B inputs is necessary if you need to detect rotation direction in addition to speed. If your code is already too slow to process one input, trying to use two inputs will only make things worse.